# Why do I need to format my usb on windows in order to use unetbootin

Tags: startup, unetbootin

If I prepare an ubuntu startup usb with unetbootin or startup disk creator, it does not boot on my pc.
But if I format the same drive on Windows, then restart on linux to create the bootable usb, it works.

(Yes, I must format the usb drive on Windows 7 first for linux to boot).

I have Gigabyte GA-880M-USB3 mainboard.

Comment: My guess would be that you need to set the boot flag on the flash drive. You can do that with gparted or fdisk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experiance is that both UNetbootin and usb-creator like FAT32.
Some flash drives come formatted FAT16.
I have had good luck formatting Live drives using gparted from the Live CD.

Comment: I format my USB drive with palimpsest. When palimpsest is about to format a partition, the option FAT means FAT16? If so, that explains it all and my question i'll format my usb a few hours from now just to find out.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try gparted next time. I hate to see Windows as the solution.